Is it natural to say that houses are "closer/lower to the ground" (compared to apartments)?

Old people like living in houses, closer to the ground compared to apartments.

I feel that this is a suitable phrase, but I googled it and didn't find many examples using it. So I'm wondering if it is naturally used.

"closer to the ground" is natural (idiomatic). https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sca_esv=db94807e8ff0f820&sca_upv=1&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&sxsrf=ADLYWIITzg8PQ71Z8tyH3i-2z80u_lrMMQ:1716891154198&q=%22closer+to+the+ground%22&tbm=bks&source=lnms&prmd=isvbmnt&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiauPT6jbCGAxUgpIkEHcPrAHgQ0pQJegQIDhAB&biw=1297&bih=665&dpr=1

@TimR - Yes, but is it ever used to distinguish a house from a high-rise flat? After all, a ground-floor flat is right on the ground!

@KateBunting I took that house/apartment contrast as merely incidental.  There are subterranean apartments  in a sci-fi book someone gave me. But they're on the moon, so maybe I shouldn't call them "subterranean".  But there are below-ground-level apartments here on planet Earth too.

I read the sentence as saying (badly) that older people like living closer to the ground than they do in apartments.  But it's just not a very well-written sentence no matter what the author was trying to say, in my opinion.

I want to say that many old people want to live in a house because it's closer to the ground so it's easier for them to get around. How about the phrase "lower to the ground"?

But look at @KateBunting’s comment: some apartments are at ground level. Whether a dwelling is a whole house or an apartment doesn’t necessarily specify how close it is to the ground.

In the UK at least, older people like to live in bungalows - single-storey houses. The upstairs of a house isn't close to the ground!

In the U.S., many one-story houses are called ranchers. (And for learners, note that @KateBunting uses the UK spelling, storey, while I use the American, story.)

Why not just say why they don't want to live "further from the ground"? It's easier for them to live in homes where they don't have to contend with stairs. I think saying that they like being closer to the ground suggests that as you get older you develop a fear of heights, which isn't really what's happening.

lower to the ground floor or level I'd say. not to the ground.

A tent is lower to the ground than a house.
Your picnic table is lower to the ground than mine.
His center of gravity is lower to the ground than mine.

Personally, I would not say live closer to the ground here  unless I were a squirrel. :). The reason you don't find it is because we don't normally associate living with close to the ground for humans as a style of living. Some birds nest close to the ground, sure.

Older people like living closer to a ground floor or ground level for purposes of entering or existing their places of residence.

older people or seniors but not old people. That is not very PC.


Old people like living in houses, closer to the ground compared to apartments.

If the sentence is for an essay, it needs to be rewritten but as we all know, proofreading is off-topic on ELL. Which is why I'm going to break with policy because there are many things in this sentence that an English language learner could… learn.
Instead of "old people" use a more polite, less stigmatised expression such as senior citizens or add an age group; e.g. people aged 65 and over
The verb like is simplistic and begs the question whether retirees would in fact not prefer to live in a luxurious villa, or a high-rise apartment complete with mod cons, and its own elevator. Replace the verb "like" with a longer phrase such as “… given a choice, many senior citizens would move to…”

mod cons
(British informal): Mod cons (modern conveniences) are the modern facilities in a house that make it easy and pleasant to live in.
Source: Collins

When providing a reason for living in a house, the expression "closer to the ground" is not idiomatic.
Give suggestions of what type of homes a person with issues of mobility or someone who is advanced in years might prefer:

a bungalow


A bungalow is a house which has only one level, and no stairs.
Source: Collins


A single-storey building
a ground floor flat


British English: The ground floor of a building is the floor that is level or almost level with the ground outside.
Jenny now lives in a terraced ground floor flat.
Source: Collins

My version

As people grow older, and their mobility becomes impaired, some choose to live in a home without stairs or steps. This might also include first-floor flats (UK) or second-floor apartments (US) as long as there is an elevator (UK lift) in the building.


The house is not closer to the ground (most houses rest on the ground, unless built in trees), the people like living... closer to the ground. Therefore that sentence is awkward.
One could change the word order, "Old people like living closer to the ground, in houses, compared to apartments." It's still not great ("old people" could be seen as disrespectful -- try a euphemism).
